# No servers listed in TFS BuildNotification.exe

Tags: tfs

When I start BuildNotification, I get this balloon:

[image]

If I click on the balloon, I get the Build Status screen with nothing listed.  If I click on the "options" menu, it is blank as well:

[image]

This was working when I left the office on Friday; but now I have this issue (and I'm the only one on the team who has this issue).

I checked the following registry key:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation\Build\BuildNotification**

but saw nothing of value. (e.g. uri = "tfs.myserver.com")

I would think it would check this registry key because it has the server listed:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation\Instances**

How does BuildNotification.exe get the server list?

Is there a way to force a refresh of this?

---

**NOTE:**  Team Explorer in Visual Studio works fine (e.g. has my TFS server info)

Comment: You can connect with Vstudio to your Collection(s)? Typically this would happen if you 'd loose your right.

Comment: @pantelif Should've mentioned earlier:  Team Explorer works fine.  It's just Build Notification that has empty server list.  Question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh.

I noticed my TFS projects weren't connected either, so I opened source control explorer and found the following option (Go Online):

[image]

Apparently, I was "offline" from the TFS server.

Only a few hours into the day and I'm already face-palming (*at myself*); gonna be a long week.

Comment: Someone on my team is having this issue with VS2013, but we are using GIT with TFS2013 and don't have "source control explorer".

Answer (score 11):

Also - If you have more than one version of VS installed, note that each version of TFS buildNotification is hooked up to the corresponding VS tfs repository address. I had changed address of VS2013 tfs connection (the old tfs address was shut down), but not on VS2012, thus when starting the VS 2012 buildNotification tool from system tray it could not connect to the new address of the tfs repository.

locations of buildnotification Tool for VS 2012 and 2013:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  11.0\Common7\IDE\BuildNotification.exe
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
  12.0\Common7\IDE\BuildNotificationApp.exe